# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle Overriding Forms : could not load type error

Tags: forms, symfony, overriding

I am trying to override FOSUserBundle for the only reason that I can put a defaut value while building the form so I don't get inappropriate validation message on laoding the form...

I am following [the doc](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md). I have put in `Etienne/UserBundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php`

```
     <?php


     namespace Etienne\UserBundle\Form\Type;

     use Symfony\Component\Form\BaseType;
     use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
     use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
     use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

     class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
   {

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder

        ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
            'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
            'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
        ))
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => $this->class,
        'intention'  => 'registration',
    ));
   }

public function getName()
{
    return 'etienne_user_registration';
}
}
```

`Etienne/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml`:

```
 services:
     etienne_user.registration.form.type:
        class: Etienne\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType
        arguments: [%fos_user.model.user.class%]
        tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: etienne_user_registration }
```

and in `app/config`:

```
 FOS_User
    registration:
         form:
             type: etienne_user_registration
```

I got this error msg:

> /var/www/projet_etienne_auth/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php at line 95

```
        if (!$type) {
            throw new FormException(sprintf('Could not load type "%s"', $name));
        }
        $this->resolveAndAddType($type);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem was i did not have an EtienneUserExtension.php file in my Dependency injection  folder (incorrect bundle install ) so the services.xml could not be loaded

Answer (score 1):

In this piece of code you firstly import `BaseType` class from Symfony's `Form` component and later define alias with same name for `RegistrationFormType` from `FOS`.

```
 use Symfony\Component\Form\BaseType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
 use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
 use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;
```

Just drop this declaration (you don't need it) and everything should be fine:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\BaseType;
```

Comment: in the doc it says that it should extend baseType and in my defaut FosSuser RegistrationFormType, it does extend AbstractType...what's the difference between the two..i have tried both anyhow

Comment: BaseType is just an alias for RegistrationFormType (in your case). It is not a separate class.